# Angular - Memory leak: mainly in FireFox and IE

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer, firefox, memory-leaks, controller

I have memory leak somewhere in my application...
Memory is going up when switching views (routing) and also, after few routing, when there is no action by the user.

This leak is not consistent - can make same scenario with no memory issues.

In Chrome browser - seems to be OK always.
FF and IE are more "problematic".

In every controller, the Intervals/Timeouts are canceled and null-ed.
Seems like there are no global variables (almost sure of that).

I used angular plugin name "sizeof.js" and by its results - the size of services is not increased...

How can I isolate the problem?
Can I find if/which references to DOM elements are not cleared?
Can I investigate the heap to relate memory allocation to specific var/object/data/...?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Amir.

Comment: How are you certain this is a memory leak? Are you saying there is no problem at all in chrome? You need a ton more information to get help here, maybe find a part of the code you are sure has a problem and show that?

Comment: "Task Manager" of my application, memory is keep going up. isn't this memory leak...?

Comment: Could be. But it's strange its only only 2 browsers. Still, if you think it's a leak you could try ng-inspector addon and that will give you an idea of what angular is still running on, i think firefox has an equivalent addon. Also with chrome you can take a HEAP snapshot and look into it - but you have to do your own digging to see what it is connected to. Is this a freshly built application, what libraries/frameworks are you using? It is really tough to tell you how to isolate without having more details.

Comment: I have the same problem. My computer has 8gb of ram, and Firefox after some time playing with ng serve,  would use too much memory that even my swap was getting full causing my OS to crash. In chromium even after Hours, the overall memory usage on my computer wouldn't exceed 3.8gb. So this has something to do with Firefox.